# Slideshow causing drop down menu to be constantly down

Tags: jquery, html, drop-down-menu, notepad++, slideshow

Can someone please help me with my coding issue? I have searched for an answer but I cannot find my specific problem and I honestly don't know how to fix it as I cannot really write code. I can read it a bit and change it with some help from the internet.

Since adding in the slideshow on the page the drop down menu is constantly down but not in the same way as it would be when you hover over it. (I added a link to the image) It still works when you hover over it then it looks like it should when hovered over, but as soon as you remove the mouse it returns to the constant down menu.

EDIT: I took the slideshow out and everything returned to normal. Then I added it in again and the same thing happened. I then thought maybe it was where I placed it, so just for the heck of it I added it in at the bottom of the page and the same thing happened with the drop down menu. So no matter where I place it, it causes the drop down menu to basically malfunction.
I have not changed anything in the coding of the slideshow, not even the image names.

EDIT 2: Tried to find the answer on Google by typing different wording but the only results it throws out are the drop down menus behind the slideshow which is not my problem at all.

EDIT 3: I deleted most of the unnecessary code as suggested and tried leaving the part where I suspect the problem lies which I suspect might be the code for the menu tabs and the slideshow. It still looks like a lot but it is only the menu code and slideshow code.

This is what it looks like when you don't hover over it:(Tried to post an image but I can't yet so this is the link to it)

https://flic.kr/p/BCiYwj

Here is the coding: (I hope it works and that I figured out how to post it)

```
    <ul class="sf-menu">
        <li class="bgr"><a href="index.html">About Us</a></li>
        <li class="bgr"><a href="Riding_School.html">Riding School</a>
            <ul>
               <li><a href="Our_Riding_School.html">Our Riding School</a>       </li>
               <li><a href="Show_Results.html">Show Results</a>
               <li><a href="Pony_Rides.html">Pony Rides</a>
               <li><a href="#">Outrides</a>
               <li><a href="#">Holiday Camps</a>
               <li><a href="Horse_Clinics.html">Horse Clinics</a>
               <li><a href="#">Farm Animals</a>
               <li><a href="#">Gallery</a>                         
               </li>
            </ul>
        </li>
        <li class="bgr"><a href="Kids_Party_Venue.html">Kids Party Venue</a>      </li>
        <li class="bgr"><a href="#">Wedding Venue</a></li>
        <li class="bgr"><a href="#">Stabling</a></li>
        <li class="bgr"><a href="#">Contact Us</a></li>
    </ul>
</nav> 
</div>
</div> 
</header>

<!--==============================content================================-->

<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
<title></title>
</head>
<body style="padding:0px; margin:0px; background-color:#fff;">

<!-- #region Jssor Slider Begin -->

<!-- Generated by Jssor Slider Maker Online. -->
<!-- This demo works with jquery library -->

<script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery-1.9.1.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/jssor.slider.mini.js"></script>
<!-- use jssor.slider.debug.js instead for debug -->
<script>
jQuery(document).ready(function ($) {

var jssor_1_SlideshowTransitions = [
  {$Duration:1200,x:0.3,$During:{$Left:[0.3,0.7]},$Easing: {$Left:$Jease$.$InCubic,$Opacity:$Jease$.$Linear},$Opacity:2},
  {$Duration:1200,x:-0.3,$SlideOut:true,$Easing:{$Left:$Jease$.$InCubic,$Opacity:$Jease$.$Linear},$Opacity:2},
  {$Duration:1200,x:-0.3,$During:{$Left:[0.3,0.7]},$Easing:{$Left:$Jease$.$InCubic,$Opacity:$Jease$.$Linear},$Opacity:2},
  {$Duration:1200,x:0.3,$SlideOut:true,$Easing:{$Left:$Jease$.$InCubic,$Opacity:$Jease$.$Linear},$Opacity:2},
  {$Duration:1200,y:0.3,$During:{$Top:[0.3,0.7]},$Easing:{$Top:$Jease$.$InCubic,$Opacity:$Jease$.$Linear},$Opacity:2},
  {$Duration:1200,y:-0.3,$SlideOut:true,$Easing:{$Top:$Jease$.$InCubic,$Opacity:$Jease$.$Linear},$Opacity:2},
  {$Duration:1200,y:-0.3,$During:{$Top:[0.3,0.7]},$Easing:{$Top:$Jease$.$InCubic,$Opacity:$Jease$.$Linear},$Opacity:2},
  {$Duration:1200,y:0.3,$SlideOut:true,$Easing:{$Top:$Jease$.$InCubic,$Opacity:$Jease$.$Linear},$Opacity:2},
  {$Duration:1200,x:0.3,$Cols:2,$During:{$Left:[0.3,0.7]},$ChessMode:{$Column:3},$Easing:{$Left:$Jease$.$InCubic,$Opacity:$Jease$.$Linear},$Opacity:2},
  {$Duration:1200,x:0.3,$Cols:2,$SlideOut:true,$ChessMode:{$Column:3},$Easing:{$Left:$Jease$.$InCubic,$Opacity:$Jease$.$Linear},$Opacity:2},
  {$Duration:1200,y:0.3,$Rows:2,$During:{$Top:[0.3,0.7]},$ChessMode:{$Row:12},$Easing:{$Top:$Jease$.$InCubic,$Opacity:$Jease$.$Linear},$Opacity:2},
  {$Duration:1200,y:0.3,$Rows:2,$SlideOut:true,$ChessMode:{$Row:12},$Easing:{$Top:$Jease$.$InCubic,$Opacity:$Jease$.$Linear},$Opacity:2},
  {$Duration:1200,y:0.3,$Cols:2,$During:{$Top:[0.3,0.7]},$ChessMode:{$Column:12},$Easing:{$Top:$Jease$.$InCubic,$Opacity:$Jease$.$Linear},$Opacity:2},
  {$Duration:1200,y:-0.3,$Cols:2,$SlideOut:true,$ChessMode:{$Column:12},$Easing:{$Top:$Jease$.$InCubic,$Opacity:$Jease$.$Linear},$Opacity:2},
  {$Duration:1200,x:0.3,$Rows:2,$During:{$Left:[0.3,0.7]},$ChessMode:{$Row:3},$Easing:{$Left:$Jease$.$InCubic,$Opacity:$Jease$.$Linear},$Opacity:2},
  {$Duration:1200,x:-0.3,$Rows:2,$SlideOut:true,$ChessMode:{$Row:3},$Easing:{$Left:$Jease$.$InCubic,$Opacity:$Jease$.$Linear},$Opacity:2},
  {$Duration:1200,x:0.3,y:0.3,$Cols:2,$Rows:2,$During:{$Left:[0.3,0.7],$Top:[0.3,0.7]},$ChessMode:{$Column:3,$Row:12},$Easing:{$Left:$Jease$.$InCubic,$Top:$Jease$.$InCubic,$Opacity:$Jease$.$Linear},$Opacity:2},
  {$Duration:1200,x:0.3,y:0.3,$Cols:2,$Rows:2,$During:{$Left:[0.3,0.7],$Top:[0.3,0.7]},$SlideOut:true,$ChessMode:{$Column:3,$Row:12},$Easing:{$Left:$Jease$.$InCubic,$Top:$Jease$.$InCubic,$Opacity:$Jease$.$Linear},$Opacity:2},
  {$Duration:1200,$Delay:20,$Clip:3,$Assembly:260,$Easing:{$Clip:$Jease$.$InCubic,$Opacity:$Jease$.$Linear},$Opacity:2},
  {$Duration:1200,$Delay:20,$Clip:3,$SlideOut:true,$Assembly:260,$Easing:{$Clip:$Jease$.$OutCubic,$Opacity:$Jease$.$Linear},$Opacity:2},
  {$Duration:1200,$Delay:20,$Clip:12,$Assembly:260,$Easing:{$Clip:$Jease$.$InCubic,$Opacity:$Jease$.$Linear},$Opacity:2},
  {$Duration:1200,$Delay:20,$Clip:12,$SlideOut:true,$Assembly:260,$Easing:  {$Clip:$Jease$.$OutCubic,$Opacity:$Jease$.$Linear},$Opacity:2}
];

var jssor_1_options = {
  $AutoPlay: true,
  $SlideshowOptions: {
    $Class: $JssorSlideshowRunner$,
    $Transitions: jssor_1_SlideshowTransitions,
    $TransitionsOrder: 1
  },
  $ArrowNavigatorOptions: {
    $Class: $JssorArrowNavigator$
  },
  $ThumbnailNavigatorOptions: {
    $Class: $JssorThumbnailNavigator$,
    $Cols: 10,
    $SpacingX: 8,
    $SpacingY: 8,
    $Align: 360
  }
};

var jssor_1_slider = new $JssorSlider$("jssor_1", jssor_1_options);

//responsive code begin
//you can remove responsive code if you don't want the slider scales while   window resizing
function ScaleSlider() {
    var refSize = jssor_1_slider.$Elmt.parentNode.clientWidth;
    if (refSize) {
        refSize = Math.min(refSize, 800);
        jssor_1_slider.$ScaleWidth(refSize);
    }
    else {
        window.setTimeout(ScaleSlider, 30);
    }
}
ScaleSlider();
$(window).bind("load", ScaleSlider);
$(window).bind("resize", ScaleSlider);
$(window).bind("orientationchange", ScaleSlider);
//responsive code end
});
</script>

<style>

/* jssor slider arrow navigator skin 05 css */
/*
.jssora05l                  (normal)
.jssora05r                  (normal)
.jssora05l:hover            (normal mouseover)
.jssora05r:hover            (normal mouseover)
.jssora05l.jssora05ldn      (mousedown)
.jssora05r.jssora05rdn      (mousedown)
*/
.jssora05l, .jssora05r {
display: block;
position: absolute;
/* size of arrow element */
width: 40px;
height: 40px;
cursor: pointer;
background: url('img/a17.png') no-repeat;
overflow: hidden;
}
.jssora05l { background-position: -10px -40px; }
.jssora05r { background-position: -70px -40px; }
.jssora05l:hover { background-position: -130px -40px; }
.jssora05r:hover { background-position: -190px -40px; }
.jssora05l.jssora05ldn { background-position: -250px -40px; }
.jssora05r.jssora05rdn { background-position: -310px -40px; }

/* jssor slider thumbnail navigator skin 01 css */
/*
```

.jssort01 .p            (normal)
    .jssort01 .p:hover      (normal mouseover)
    .jssort01 .p.pav        (active)
    .jssort01 .p.pdn        (mousedown)
    */
    .jssort01 .p {
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    width: 72px;
    height: 72px;
    }

```
.jssort01 .t {
position: absolute;
top: 0;
left: 0;
width: 100%;
height: 100%;
border: none;
}

.jssort01 .w {
position: absolute;
top: 0px;
left: 0px;
width: 100%;
height: 100%;
}

.jssort01 .c {
position: absolute;
top: 0px;
left: 0px;
width: 68px;
height: 68px;
border: #000 2px solid;
box-sizing: content-box;
background: url('img/t01.png') -800px -800px no-repeat;
_background: none;
}

.jssort01 .pav .c {
top: 2px;
_top: 0px;
left: 2px;
_left: 0px;
width: 68px;
height: 68px;
border: #000 0px solid;
_border: #fff 2px solid;
background-position: 50% 50%;
}

.jssort01 .p:hover .c {
top: 0px;
left: 0px;
width: 70px;
height: 70px;
border: #fff 1px solid;
background-position: 50% 50%;
}

.jssort01 .p.pdn .c {
background-position: 50% 50%;
width: 68px;
height: 68px;
border: #000 2px solid;
}

* html .jssort01 .c, * html .jssort01 .pdn .c, * html .jssort01 .pav .c {
/* ie quirks mode adjust */
width /**/: 72px;
height /**/: 72px;
}

</style>


<div id="jssor_1" style="position: relative; margin: 0 auto; top: 0px; left:  0px; width: 800px; height: 456px; overflow: hidden; visibility: hidden; background-color: #24262e;">
<!-- Loading Screen -->
<div data-u="loading" style="position: absolute; top: 0px; left: 0px;">
<div style="filter: alpha(opacity=70); opacity: 0.7; position: absolute;   display: block; top: 0px; left: 0px; width: 100%; height: 100%;">   </div>
<div   style="position:absolute;display:block;background:url('img/loading.gif') no-repeat center center;top:0px;left:0px;width:100%;height:100%;"></div>
</div>
<div data-u="slides" style="cursor: default; position: relative; top: 0px; left: 0px; width: 800px; height: 356px; overflow: hidden;">
<div data-p="144.50" style="display: none;">
    <img data-u="image" src="img/01.jpg" />
    <img data-u="thumb" src="img/thumb-01.jpg" />
</div>
<div data-p="144.50" style="display: none;">
    <img data-u="image" src="img/02.jpg" />
    <img data-u="thumb" src="img/thumb-02.jpg" />
</div>
<div data-p="144.50" style="display: none;">
    <img data-u="image" src="img/03.jpg" />
    <img data-u="thumb" src="img/thumb-03.jpg" />
</div>
<div data-p="144.50" style="display: none;">
    <img data-u="image" src="img/04.jpg" />
    <img data-u="thumb" src="img/thumb-04.jpg" />
</div>
<div data-p="144.50" style="display: none;">
    <img data-u="image" src="img/05.jpg" />
    <img data-u="thumb" src="img/thumb-05.jpg" />
</div>
<div data-p="144.50" style="display: none;">
    <img data-u="image" src="img/06.jpg" />
    <img data-u="thumb" src="img/thumb-06.jpg" />
</div>
<div data-p="144.50" style="display: none;">
    <img data-u="image" src="img/07.jpg" />
    <img data-u="thumb" src="img/thumb-07.jpg" />
</div>
<div data-p="144.50" style="display: none;">
    <img data-u="image" src="img/08.jpg" />
    <img data-u="thumb" src="img/thumb-08.jpg" />
</div>
<div data-p="144.50" style="display: none;">
    <img data-u="image" src="img/09.jpg" />
    <img data-u="thumb" src="img/thumb-09.jpg" />
</div>
<div data-p="144.50" style="display: none;">
    <img data-u="image" src="img/10.jpg" />
    <img data-u="thumb" src="img/thumb-10.jpg" />
</div>
<div data-p="144.50" style="display: none;">
    <img data-u="image" src="img/11.jpg" />
    <img data-u="thumb" src="img/thumb-11.jpg" />
</div>
<div data-p="144.50" style="display: none;">
    <img data-u="image" src="img/12.jpg" />
    <img data-u="thumb" src="img/thumb-12.jpg" />
</div>
</div>
<!-- Thumbnail Navigator -->
<div data-u="thumbnavigator" class="jssort01" style="position:absolute;left:0px;bottom:0px;width:800px;height:100px;" data-autocenter="1">
<!-- Thumbnail Item Skin Begin -->
<div data-u="slides" style="cursor: default;">
    <div data-u="prototype" class="p">
        <div class="w">
            <div data-u="thumbnailtemplate" class="t"></div>
        </div>
        <div class="c"></div>
    </div>
</div>
<!-- Thumbnail Item Skin End -->
</div>
<!-- Arrow Navigator -->
<span data-u="arrowleft" class="jssora05l" style="top:158px;left:8px;width:40px;height:40px;"></span>
<span data-u="arrowright" class="jssora05r" style="top:158px;right:8px;width:40px;height:40px;"></span>
<a href="http://www.jssor.com" style="display:none">Bootstrap Carousel</a>
</div>

<!-- #endregion Jssor Slider End -->
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Hoping to bump this to the top for help

Comment: Welcome to **Stack Overflow** which "is a question and answer site for professional and enthusiast programmers" (see [tour]). Your question opens by saying that you *"cannot write code"*. The question you have posed contains a huge lump of html. Expecting anyone to wade through that to try and find the piece that relates to a poorly explained problem is asking a lot. Please read [mcve] and use its great ideas to simplify your question.

Comment: Thank you for your response. I will have a look at the link and update my question. Thought if I posted the whole page's code it will be better than just a bit.